# I am trying to take a large binary file as an input to FPGA directly through a pendrive

Tags: large-files, fpga, usb-drive

The file is a binary file with size of around 10 GB and I don't want to send the data by reading it through a computer. Is there any way to do it. I have also not yet purchased a FPGA board. So which board is preferred to do such a task

Answer (score 0):

One with a usb host interface phy and a microprocessor running an embedded OS with the appropriate usb drivers.

This would be a good place to start.
http://www.zedboard.org/content/key-features

Of course it also depends where you are going to send the data and what interface you need.